# Trying to dual boot Windows 2016 and Centos 7 - won't boot if drive set to UEFI

Tags: centos, dual-boot, uefi

Motherboard: SuperMicro X11SCA-F, BIOS v2.2

- I installed Windows 2016 on a 2TB nvme drive, which booted and worked as I'd expect.
- I then installed CentOS 7.9 in the spare partition, then rebooted.
- It tries to PXE boot unless I change the drive type in the BIOS from UEFI, and then it will boot, but only offer CentOS as an option.

When I run `grub2-mkconfig > /dev/null` it only finds the two LOinux images, and `os-prober` shows nothing at all.

If I examine the partitions with `parted`, I get:

```
Model: NVMe Device (nvme)
Disk /dev/nvme0n1: 2048GB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/512B
Partition Table: gpt
Disk Flags: pmbr_boot

Number  Start   End     Size    File system  Name                          Flags
 1      1049kB  473MB   472MB   ntfs         Basic data partition          hidden, diag
 2      473MB   577MB   104MB   fat32        EFI system partition          boot
 3      577MB   593MB   16.8MB               Microsoft reserved partition  msftres
 4      593MB   268GB   268GB   ntfs         Basic data partition
 5      268GB   268GB   1049kB                                             bios_grub
 6      268GB   270GB   1074MB  xfs
 7      270GB   2048GB  1779GB                                             lvm
```

I have `ntfs-3g` installed and can mount partition 4 without any issues.

What am I mising here?

Comment: Windows is on a gpt partitioned drive and has in ESP - efi system partition. For grub to boot Windows you have to have installed in UEFI boot mode. The bios_grub partition is only used for gpt drives and old BIOS boot. Boot into Centos, mount ESP and install grub's UEFI version. i only know how to do from Ubuntu. Or reinstall in UEFI mode. How you boot install media UEFI or BIOS is then how it installs.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to oldfred's suggestion. It turned out I'd formatted the CentOS USB flash drive in Rufus as MBT rather than GPT/UEFI, and the mobo was installing CentOS in legacy rather than UEFI mode, despite me having all the boot devices set to UEFI in the BIOS.

I reinstalled CentOS from a USB flash drive formatted with GPT/EFI, and it installed without issues, detected the Windows 2016 installation, and I can now boot either.